# Can a program output be redirected to a pipe through program itself?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, filestream

Well this is regarding a program for a competition.

I was submitting a program & finding my metrics to be relatively way slower than the top scorers in terms of total execution speed. All others (page faults, memory...) were similar. I found that when I ran through my program without the printf (or write) my total execution speed (as measured in my own pc) seemed to be similar.

The competition evaluates the output by redirecting the output (with a pipe, i suppose) into a file & matching its MD5 with theirs....

My question is, Is there by any means something in C, that doesn't write to the output stream but still the pipe gets its input. Or perhaps I am even framing the question wrong. But either way, I am in a fix.

I have been beating my head off with optimizing the algorithm. BTW they accept makefile where many have tried to optimize.  For me neither of the optimization flags have worked. I don't know what else can be done about that too...

Comment: `stdout` should be buffered, should incur a fairly low overhead. could you try changing your `printf` calls to `sprintf` into a buffer, see if it still performs badly? also, does your output require formatting?

Comment: If they redirect the output to file, why don't you do it externally the way they do it? When you execute the command in linux, write: `./program > my_output`

Comment: @Hasturkun. Each test case produces an output of less than 512 characters & 512 was my buffer size... What buffer size would you suggest, as I don't know the number of test cases.

Comment: @Shahbaz I cant know where they redirect my output to.

Comment: @loxxy: My suggestion re `sprintf` was mostly to see if you're suffering from overhead due to the `printf` call itself, ie. do the formatting without actual output. This is mostly because I don't know how your data is represented and output. a code snippet may help

Comment: _Is there by any means something in C, that doesn't write to the output stream but still the pipe gets its input?_ The pipe gets as input, the output of your program. What do you mean by that question?

Comment: @Hasturkun my output is an array of characters at every test case. I have tried printf, sprintf, write & putchar.... all minor changes. But I f i remove that single statement, the execution time goes way down.

Comment: @Shahbaz The pipe gets what I write to stdout. My write to stdout takes long. 'Something in C' refers to 'some solution to my problem in C'.

Comment: I don't think you can get around that. Writing to stdout will take some time, regardless of how you do it.

Comment: @loxxy: can I assume you also tried `fwrite`?

Comment: @Hasturkun No I didn't. I'll report after submitting once more though I doubt that would change anything...

Comment: QuantumPete is right, there cant be a sol for this. Well thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to make a program that writes its output to a file, you just need to:

- open the file with `int fd = fopen("/file/path", O_WRONLY);` (you may need to check the parameters, it's been a long time since I've done C programming) and then `write(fd, ...);` or `fprintf(fd, ...);`
- open the file with fopen, close the standard output and use `dup2()` to duplicate the file descriptor to the file descriptor number 1 (i.e. standard output).

Comment: I don't need to write to a file. I need to write it to stdout itself as they redirect it to some file. All I know is that this 'writing to stdout' part is taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

You may try fprintf on the pipe fd.

Comment: I cant have the file descriptor of the pipe they use, can I?